# Xcode 6 - Storyboard UINavigation Back Button not appearing in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a `NavigationController` embedded within a `TableViewController`:

[image]

My Issue I am having is I can't get the back button to appear in my app :(

[image]

Is there a step I am missing here ?

Comment: The back button itself doesn't appear or the word Menu doesn't appear as the back button title?

Comment: Is it because you _added_ a navigation item instead of using the one that comes with the VC?

Comment: I think soulshined may be right, here. I've had this problem before, and it was because I had messed too much with the navigation controller at the top. Adding or removing bar items can mess it up, or even changing the order of the navigation segues. Have you done anything like that?

Comment: Use the navigation bar of the VC itself rather than creating a new navigation bar

Comment: that button appears only when you push something, you can place another button at the same place and use it as back button

Answer (score 1):

Back button appears only after you push a `ViewController` over another one.

In this image you only set the RootViewController of your NavigationController so you have nowhere to go back so that's why back button does not appear.

You can still put programatically a button that does what you need.